Modelling intervention study using LME4 and participants are nested in subgroups in one group only
We conducted a behavior change field experiment using the following variables:

Two time points (T0, T1)
Two groups (intervention vs. control)(n = 62 in group 1, n = 53 in group 2)
Workshop ID (7 workshops in group 1, 1 dummy workshop in group 2)

We are analyzing the data in lme4 using this model
This is our model:
lmer(DV_T1 ~ 1 + group + DV_T0 + (1|workshop_id), data=df)

However, only group1 participants are nested within subgroups (not control participants), so to model the random effect of workshop day, we made a fake subgroup for all control participants. This random effect structure (having all control participants in the same “workshop day”) might mirror the main group effect (intervention vs. control) and thereby cloud some of that main effect of the intervention.
Do you think this is an issue and would there be a way to model random subgroup effects differently?

I'm still slightly confused by your terminology. I understand that group1==intervention, group2==control. What is a "subgroup"? Is it the same as a "workshop ID", which is also the same as a "workshop day"? Are you saying that there's basically one fake "workshop day"/level of workshop_ID for all of the control participants plus (real) 8 levels for the subjects in the intervention group?

Thank you very much for your help! Yes subgroup is the same as workshop ID. Indeed, so there are 7 real subgroups in the intervention group and one fake subgroup for all workshop participants.

Please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only as a comment. Comments are seen by few people, and can be removed. Particularly, you responded to a question by @BenBolker  but there is no guarantee he will see your answer, unless you ping him as I have did (with @...) here ...
